# Is the function below bijective?

Tags: functions

Let $ n \in \mathbb N^* $. Is the following function bijective ?
$$ f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R \quad f(x) = x^n  $$

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: What is $\mathbb N^*$?  And is $n$ odd, even, prime, ... etc...?

Comment: @fleablood $$ \mathbb N = {1;2;3;4;.....} $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** discuss the cases when $n$ is odd and even. Look at $f(\pm1)$ in one of the two cases, and in the other case, consider whether or not $f$ is monotonic.

Comment: Can i have an answer, please ?

Comment: @Youssef no. I an not going to do your homework for you, if you can't even bother to think about it yourself.